# Entity Framework, Projections, and Relations (oh my?)

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, dbcontext

So, I'm working on new software, but I have no choice but to brownfield the database.  I would like to use Entity Framework where it makes sense.

Here's my dilemma:

- Since the tables are very wide, and I can't change this, I will probably make heavy use of projection to limit the width of the datasets that I query.
- I do want to make use of navigation properties where it makes sense
- From what I've seen, a lot of people use a model where there is a single DbContext class for the whole project.

So,

I'm weighing these pro's and cons, and I'm wondering what the established best practices might be:

- Use 1 DbContext.

  - There could be A LOT of "pollution" here, with bunches of projections of the data inside of the 1 context class.  This sounds like it could become a maintenance nightmare.
- Don't make my projections dbsets at all -- just make them plain old objects and select new MyProject {..} into them.

  - This offers the benefit of keeping my projections in module-specific assemblies and namespaces, but now I get NO navigation/lazy loading/ etc.
- Be evil?? and use multiple DbContexts?

  - I'm not really sure what the maintenance story looks like here, but I'm kind of starting to lean in this direction.  My biggest problem with it is that it feels like I'm swimming against the current -- not many people seem to do this, but for a large system, it seems like it could be the best option.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use POCO or DTO for data transfer between different layers of application. Use ViewModel to send data to View.

Consider using Repository Pattern  and UoW to have a better and efficient architecture in this scenario. Limit the use of  navigation properties till repository otherwise they makes entity heavy while transferring those across layers (Use POCO or DTO).

If you are doing as above, then I do not think using multiple DbContexts would give you any benefit. Thanks.